# How to avoid requests.exceptions.ConnectionError for printing url text?

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, text, python-requests

I cannot print the text of the url. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.autozone.com/ecomm/b2c/v1/browse/page/getProductFitVehicles?skuId=937722&productLineCode=NGK&partNumber=4469')

print(r.text)
```

Traceback

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a user agent, it doesnt even have to be something coherent

```
import requests
#Set headers
headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'}
#Add , headers=headers at the end of line before closing the parentheses
r = requests.get('https://www.autozone.com/ecomm/b2c/v1/browse/page/getProductFitVehicles?skuId=937722&productLineCode=NGK&partNumber=4469', headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Hello, This is still returning an error. requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
>>>

Comment: What version of python are you using??

Comment: Wait are you using a proxy or a vpn??

Answer (score 0):

r is not a variable but an object. Seems like you want to print the responce, try this:

```
print(r.content)
```

**OR**

```
print(r.text)
```

Comment: the last line of the script is print(r.text)

Comment: I know, i was pointing out that .consent is used much more frequenly than .text. Now however, if your connections gets reseted by the peer, try to ping the host using your terminal to see if its an error coming from your side or the url itself. Try to also access it from your browser.